# How to change an images source upon hover?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

Im trying to make an image change source upon mouse over using a combination of asp.net and javascript, this is the code I'm using

```
<asp:ImageButton id="button" runat="server" Height="65px" ImageUrl="~/images/logo.png"   OnMouseOver="src='~/images/hover.png';" OnMouseOut="src='~/images/logo.png';">
```

It displays initially, but then upon hovering it changes to this. I have confirmed there is a photo named hover.png in the directory.

[image: {X}]

Thanks for the help! I don't mind completely changing the code if necessary.

Comment: I suggest firing up fiddler to see what is happening. It will show you specifically which image it is trying to get and if it is able to get it.

Comment: Just curious, why not just use CSS and :hover?

Answer (score 0):

If that's the problem and the src is now `/images/hover.png` and you're getting that image. Then here would be a trick to find out why that happened.

Go to the Browser's Console and look for the Network tab to see how the image was requested and what was the response of the Server for that image. If that's a 404, then make sure that the Image Link is accurate.

Secondly you can also try out the jQuery event handlers.

```
$('img').hover(function () {
  $(this).attr('src', '/images/hover.png');
});
```

This would update the attribute of the image upon a hover event. Here is a fiddle that I have made up for you to understand this method.

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/k4shj/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `~` from the `src` attribute since this is a client side code (not server side)

```
<asp:ImageButton id="button" runat="server" Height="65px" ImageUrl="~/images/logo.png"   OnMouseOver="src='/images/hover.png';" OnMouseOut="src='/images/logo.png';">
                                                                                                         ^^^^                                  ^^^^
```